# Reading and writing data to a property list

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I know this question has been asked a hundred times here because I have been reading most of the questions about reading and writing to plists in this forum, in fact this is the main reason why I'm posting this question. I'm tired of trying outdated tutorials about this topic. I have tried a few tutorials but most of them are using .xib files or are not using ARC and I usually end up with a bunch of errors.

Does anyone know about a tutorial about reading/writing to a plist that uses storyboards and ARC? In other words an updated tutorial.

All I need is a tutorial that I can reference to have a better understanding on how to persist data using plists.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Reading and writing to a plist has nothing to do with xib files or storyboards. On the other hand, ARC makes only a difference when instantiating objects, but the reading and writing methods should work without change. Why don't you post the code you have tried and I'm sure there must be just a few details that we can correct.

Comment: Have you read [Apple's Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: This link may solve my lack of understanding plists in general and the way they are saved/load. I will go through this documentation, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Merlevede  - the very first tutorial I tried was http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/ but now that you are pointing out that the methods should be the same I may gieve it another shot since as soon as I got errors I was assuming that it was because of some depricated code, and didn't try any further. I tried a video from lynda.com and on that one I din't get any errors I just couldn't make it to work and since the code was from 2012 I thouhgt the same thing, that it was some depricated code.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial on reading and writing plists using storyboards and ARC is like asking for a tutorial on making pancakes while wearing a blue shirt and sneakers. As @Merlevede says, plists and storyboards have absolutely nothing to do with each other. plists are just a way to save certain types of objects to a file. ("Property list Objects" or collections of property list objects. The only objects that are property list objects are NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects.)

Comment: There isn't much to know about saving data to plists. As long as you're saving one of the Property List Objects (listed by Duncan C), then you just use the method that's appropriate to the class of object you're saving -- NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSData have writeToFile:atomically: or writeToURL:atomically:, NSString has writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:. To get the data out, you use one of the initWithContentsOfURL: or initWithContentsOfFile: methods.

Comment: @fs_tigre Stackoverflow is not a forum. There are no [solved] tags here or any other tags in the title. This is a question and answer site. You asked a question. If you managed to find a solution, then add an answer with your solution and mark by clicking the checkmark on the left. See [faq].

Comment: @fs_tigre in other words, edit your question to remove the solution, the post the solution as an answer. Also, note that requests for links to tutorials are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple piece of code that shows how to read and write to a plist. Code is based on this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I63BJ8kR4pg).

What I have here is basically two labels and two buttons on screen, one button to write the data and the other one is to read the data when clicked, the two labels are to show the first two items from an array (plist), item 0 will be shown in the first label and item 1 will be shown in the the second label.

.m file

```
-(NSString *)getFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fruitList.plist"];
}

-(void)saveData
{
    NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Orange",  @"Apple", nil];
    [value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(void)loadData
{
    NSString *myPath = [self getFilePath];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

    if(fileExists)
    {
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];

        self.labelOne.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        self.labelTwo.text = [values objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}

- (IBAction)writeData:(id)sender
{
    [self saveData];
}

- (IBAction)readData:(id)sender
{
    [self loadData];
}
```

.h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTwo;

-(NSString*) getFilePath;
-(void) saveData;
-(void) loadData;

- (IBAction)writeData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)readData:(id)sender;
```